# Common Notation for Sets or Spaces

Tags: notation

Is there some good reference (website could be better) to know the meaning of symbols (generally used) for any "special" kind of sets or spaces like $\mathbb{R}^{2}_{\geq}$?

I've looked up, without success, in:

1. Enlightening Symbols: A Short History of Mathematical Notation and its Hidden Powers (Mazur, 2016).
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols_by_subject

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^{2}_{\geq}$ does not look standard to me.  It might be intended to mean $\{(x,y)\}$ with $x \ge y$ or $\{(x,y)\}$ with $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$, or something else.  I would expected to be defined where you came across it

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^2_{\geq}$ is standard notation for the positive quadrant, including $x$ and $y$ axes.

Comment: I mean, we can't even decide whether $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ or not.

Comment: @JairTaylor:  That's a different question.  We all know that $\mathbb{N}$ denotes the "natural numbers," which is an example of the OP's question.

Comment: I've found this link, in which there is a list related to what I am looking for: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-0-387-68628-8%2F1.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I’m not quite sure this is what you’re looking for, but this is a really good reference for different types of algebraic/topological structures:

http://math.chapman.edu/~jipsen/structures/doku.php/index.html

This doesn’t have to do with notation per se, but it does demonstrate a lot of the notation used to express common algebras, topological spaces, orderings, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to explore https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page which has a more-or-less comprehensive symbols dictionary, but it's not all listed in a neat list, you need to go and find the pages the things are defined on.

Perhaps there's work for someone who has a vision of what it is they want to see in such a list.